# Unable to build my android project after changing package name

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

i was implementing an android application in kotlin , then i have changed the package name . After that , i cannot build my android project anymore and i got the error

```
> Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin FAILED
```

e: Could not load module

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s

Can someone help me to solve this ?

Comment: Did you try to invalidate & clean cache?